# Any tool to manipulate xaml in the visual way

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Besides Visual Studio, any tool from designer side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/downloads/Kaxaml_1.0.msi) and [XAMLPADX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/08/25/xamlpadx-4-0.aspx) .Also Check [here](http://www.realsoftwaredevelopment.com/the-complete-list-of-xaml-tools/) for a complete list

Answer (score 5):

[Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx).

Comment: ... made by Microsoft just for that purpose

Answer (score 1):

My workflow, such as it is, is:  prototype in Kaxaml, code in Visual Studio, prettify in Expression Blend.

There are a couple of issues I have with Kaxaml.  It takes the notion that it's a temporary scratchpad a little too seriously, letting you close the program without prompting you to save, for one.  And its exception handling is not quite robust enough; I find myself crashing it now and then by doing something wrong, which is not a very good feature in a program that's designed as a platform for trying stuff out.  But the price is right, certainly.  I use this every day - for instance, I just used it to write [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487604/setting-font-of-parent-in-nodes-in-wpf-tree-view-to-bold-using-code-behind/4488420#4488420).

I've never had any success with the designer in VS:  it seems too hard to use for simple stuff and too limited for complicated stuff.

And then there's Expression Blend.  Some days I feel like Expression Blend is the most fully-realized elaboration of a terrible idea that I've ever seen.  It's almost exactly wrong:  it's an abstraction layer in which nothing is really abstracted.  The properties window is the stuff of nightmares.  The documentation for Expression Blend is shameful, too; the help files are extremely inadequate, and the heavy use of online video instruction makes it impossible to find answers quickly.  I find myself spending a *lot* of time in the XAML editor portion of this supposed tool for designers.  And yet, once you get over its awful learning curve, and (crucially) figure out how to build view model objects that it can instantiate, it's a freaking amazing program.  Pity about the documentation.