# Setting font of parent in nodes in WPF Tree View to Bold using code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, wpf-controls, binding

I have made a tree view and added parent and child nodes to it all using code behind, now where I am stuck is to set the font of parent nodes to `BOLD` while keeping the font of child as it is, below is code that i have right now.

```
List<ParentTreeViewNode> ParentTreeViewNodeList = new List<ParentTreeViewNode>();

HierarchicalDataTemplate treeViewTemplate = new HierarchicalDataTemplate(typeof(Child));
treeViewTemplate.DataType = "{x:Type local:Child}";
treeViewTemplate.ItemsSource = new Binding("Children");

FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
tb.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
treeViewTemplate.VisualTree = tb;

DataTemplate parentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ParentTreeViewNode));
parentTemplate.DataType = "{x:Type local:ParentTreeViewNode}";
//parentTemplate.ItemsSource = new Binding("Children");

FrameworkElementFactory tbp = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
tbp.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
tbp.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green);
treeViewTemplate.VisualTree = tbp;


// ParentTreeViewNode1.Children = Childlist1;

ParentTreeViewNodeList.Add(new ParentTreeViewNode("Paren1"));
ParentTreeViewNodeList.Add(new ParentTreeViewNode("Paren2"));
ParentTreeViewNodeList.Add(new ParentTreeViewNode("Paren3"));

//arrayTreeView.ItemTemplate = treeViewTemplate;
arrayTreeView.Resources.Add(1,treeViewTemplate);
arrayTreeView.Resources.Add(2,treeViewTemplate);
arrayTreeView.ItemsSource = ParentTreeViewNodeList;
```

this is the link where i took help from:
http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/using-hierarchical-data-template-with-c-code/#comment-446

thanks

Comment: the above does not work, its just my attempt of what i thougt should be like, it Displays MYApp.App in tree nodes

Comment: Do you have to do it in the code behind? If not I think I have a solution for it using Templates.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put something like this:

```
tb.SetValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
```

or

```
tb.SetValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);
```

wher you see fit

Comment: i was asking more on the binding side. if i do this the whole tree will become bold

Comment: how to set bold so that only parent node get bold

Comment: You can call SetValue on any element. Set Bold to the parent and Normal to the children

Comment: nice idea but does not work, to get the element i need to use itemContainer which is retuning null, http://www.go4answers.com/Example/treeviewitemcontainergeneratorcontaine-154192.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you how to fix that code-behind to do that.  What I can do is tell you that you don't need code-behind to do this.  That looks like a nightmare.

Here's a simple example of how to use binding, a style, and a trigger to accomplish what you're talking about.  Don't get too overwhelmed by the fact that I'm using an `XmlDataProvider` here - that's just so that it's a working example that you can paste into Kaxaml and play with.  When I say "simple," what I mean is that the whole thing is accomplished by a single binding, a single template, and a single style.

The key here is that the style in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` sets the `FontWeight` to `Bold` by default, and then there's a `DataTrigger` that sets it to `Normal` if the item has no children.  (So you'll notice, as you expand the tree, that the fact that an item is boldfaced tells you that it has children.  Which looks kinda nice.)

If you're binding to something other than an `XmlDataSource`, you probably have a property on the source that the `DataTrigger` can check, with a value that tells you whether or not it's a child; just plug that property and value into the style.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data">
      <x:XData>
        <Data xmlns="">
          <Parent Text="This is a parent">
            <Child Text="This is a child"/>
            <Child Text="This is a child">
              <Grandchild Text="This is a grandchild"/>
              <Grandchild Text="This is a grandchild"/>
            </Child>
            <Child Text="This is a child"/>
          </Parent>
          <Parent Text="This is a parent">
            <Child Text="This is a child"/>
            <Child Text="This is a child"/>
            <Child Text="This is a child"/>
          </Parent>
        </Data>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
  </Page.Resources>
  <DockPanel>  
    <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, XPath=/Data/*}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Text}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
              <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XPath=*}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
          </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
  </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        --------------
                        --------------
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                                    Property=" TextElement.FontWeight"
                                    Value="Bold"/>
                        </Trigger>                           
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Copy the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788727%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and add this trigger.I am not sure how to do this in code.You can check this article to get some overview

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/ButtonControl.aspx

Comment: It worked for me! I needed the selected treeviewitem to be bold but not its children too and by targeting the Header part it worked. Children of the selected node were not bolded.