# Style change is applied to all children of a TreeView node

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a `TreeView` with lots of items, obviously arranged in a tree structure. I am trying to print the parent node in bold and all its children in normal font. However, when I do:

```
TreeViewItem item = GetParentNode(...);
item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

this not only changes the parent's style to bold, but also all its children's. I have been looking for properties to disable this recursive update in the `TreeView` class, but I can't find any. How do I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: are you doing all in code behind? Do you have HierarchicalDataTemplate in XAML?

Comment: I did design the `TreeView` in XAML (although the code is so simple it's hardly worth mentioning), but setting the font weights must be done programatically, as it is part of user interaction.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487604/setting-font-of-parent-in-nodes-in-wpf-tree-view-to-bold-using-code-behind
It's shown a similar problem, solved with datatriggers.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the font properties it applies it to all children.  You could create a new header template and apply it only to the nodes that are parents.

An alternative that has worked in my testing is setting the foreground color:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StyleParents(MyTreeView.Items);
    }

    private void StyleParents(ItemCollection items)
    {
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            TreeViewItem tvi = i as TreeViewItem;

            if (tvi != null)
            {
                if (tvi.HasItems)
                {
                    tvi.Foreground = Brushes.Magenta;

                    StyleParents(tvi.Items);
                }
            }                                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the WPF `TreeView`, properties are transferred onto their children if they haven't already been set. The easiest way to avoid this problem (programatically, at least) is to set the font of a child node to the default font as soon as it is created. E.g.

```
TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem ();
item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
// ...add item to tree
```

If you now set the `FontWeight` of a parent node to bold, the children will not change.